# Magento 1: Where can I find the class responsible for creating the customer through the registration form?

Tags: magento-1.9, forms, registration, customer-registration

I need to add a name check before saving the user (if it contains certain words, then don't create the user). I'm not familiar with Magento 1, so please tell me where to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the controller file

> app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php

You need to override the controller.

Comment: thank you for help